# using key of an object in single line

Tags: javascript, async-await, ethereum, web3js

Below is a simple programme which includes web3 :-

```
let web3 = require('web3');
var real = new web3(web3.givenProvider)    //  web3.givenProvider is having value of my infura endpoint

discuss();

async function discuss()
 {
let dif = await real.eth.getBlock(16532022)
let di = dif.size
console.log(di)             //    Line 1 :- displays the size

console.log(typeof dif )    // Line 2 :- returns object  

let   diftwo = await real.eth.getBlock(16532022).size ;

console.log(diftwo) ;    // Line 3 :- displays undefined
```

When I used the `.size` directly in Line 3 it is not showing the size of block. I checked the `typeof` of the `.getBlock` and saw that it is an object  which means `size` is  key of that object. So why is it not showing the  result when I used the `size` using the dot notation.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

As per me , using dot notation should have given me the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
let diftwo = (await real.eth.getBlock(16532022)).size
```

You have to wait for the `promise` to resolve and then try to get the `size` field from it.

Quick example you can try in terminal

```
let func = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    return setTimeout(() => res({result: true}), 2000)
})

await func() // This would resolve to {result: true}

await func().result // This would return undefined cause the promise is not resolved yet

(await func()).result //This would return true as promise is resolved first
```

**Note:** For the example, assuming that you have top level await

Comment: Suppose like I have to fill an excel columns with size of 100 block so waiting for getting entire block would be too much time consuming.Size is a property of `.getblock` , so instead of waiting for the whole block , I would actually like to only wait to get the size , shouldn't that be possible ?